# proteus pcb design - arranging sensitivity

Tags: proteus, sensitivity

I am so new in designing pcb,
My problem is : putting buttons horizontally at the same level,

What I do is : putting 2 buttons side by side, 
But they are not exactly at the same level, there is a little difference,

I am looking for a sensitivity setting, but I can not find.

Any help will be good for me.

Regards.

Comment: Could you add some screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two button footprints not aligned:

[image: button footprints not aligned]

Select them with your mouse by clicking and dragging, or either select them by holding `CTRL` key and clicking on them:

[image]

Go to Edit->Align menu and this will pop-up:

[image]

Select appropriate settings and click OK.. Here is the end result:

[image]

Comment: Proteus is my choice of software for my designs, and I have been using it for about 2 years now...... And I did not know this method! The one I use is the one I mentioned in my answer, but have up-voted your response as not only did it answer the question, it is also something very useful I will definitely be using this technique myself!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not have screenshots, but another way to do this is to press 'o' (which is the keyboard shortcut for origin) on the centre of the component that is in the correct place, then you can right click the one which is out of place, then right-click the component you wish to align with is and select 'move to' then you can type in the x,y co-ordinates for where you want the component to be with respect to your origin.

While the above method is very good (and one I didn't actually know so thank you, I will be using that!) being able to type in your x,y co-ordinates with respect to a pre-placed origin will enable you to precisely place components if you are making something where you need certain components at exact distances from each other or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

[image: PROTEUS PCB 1]

Just go to "Technology" then "Set Grid Snaps" and change all the values, for example if you have 1 change it to 0.1 and so on.
[image]